# Set the height of a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, height

For some reason it's not possible for me to adjust the height of a UITableView from within my controller, in my viewDidLoad I did this:

```
[self.tableView setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 100.0f)];
[self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 100.0f)];

self.tableView.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 100.0f);
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 100.0f);
```

I just tried every option, but nothing seems to change the height of my table.

Comment: It's a nib one, would that make a difference?

Comment: It is, I can do anything I want, except for changing the dimensions, this for instance works perfectly: self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: When I log out the values it gives me the correct ones.
I set the programmatically because the position and height is based on the height of another view, but in the example I just used static values.

Comment: I don't see how, even when I set the height in the nib and turn of autosizing, the height is changed when I run

Comment: OK, this is getting long, so I'll start deleting my comments.  Anyhow, is there any way you could put up a couple of screenshots?

Comment: Are you using a UITableViewController as the controller?  If so, it will automatically use the full available screen and you can not change it....  You can change to a UIViewController and implement the proper methods to make it work though.

Comment: @CodaFi Darn, turns out I was also trying to set the frame somewhere else, not sure why I did it there, but because of this code it was completely ignoring any other code that tried to set the frame.

Comment: @lnafziger I do use a UITableViewController, but this doesn't seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITableViewController will automatically make the tableview full screen.

Taken from the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH5-SW1):

> Note: You should use a UIViewController subclass rather than a
>   subclass of UITableViewController to manage a table view if the view
>   to be managed is composed of multiple subviews, one of which is a
>   table view. The default behavior of the UITableViewController class is
>   to make the table view fill the screen between the navigation bar and
>   the tab bar (if either are present).

Comment: Well, I don't know what to say, but using this just worked: 
_updates.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 75.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 75);

Comment: While it may work now, I wouldn't count on this behavior in the future as it could break at any time since Apple specifically says that you should not be using a `UITableViewController` in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UIViewController`, and add `UITableViewController` as a child view controller. Then you can add the `UITableViewController`'s view as a subview to your `UIViewController` and set the frame as you wish. You can use the `UIViewController` to control the rest of the UI elements and the `UITableViewController` to control the table.

Note that this method uses `UIViewController` containers which is an iOS 5 feature.